# Dynamic handle bar template generation and modification

Tags: web-applications, ember.js, handlebars.js

We are trying to write a reporting application which reports generated according its layout template , we are planning to use xsd or json-schema as the layout template declaration language and process this declaration  and use the output of this processing  as ember.js view .
That is when the user select this template on ember.js application  processed output (handle.bar html  template  ) will be visible on page .

How can i dynamically add this view to ember page and continue to use full ember capabilities .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your goal so well but I assume you are trying to render template dynamicly so you might wanna look at [renderTemplate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) and [rendering-template guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/)